# How do we use *args and **kwargs with decorators

Tags: python, dictionary, decorator, args, keyword-argument

i don't get why are we doing that args[0]["valid"] instead of just args["valid"]

```
 user1 = {
    'name': 'Sorna',
    'valid': True
}

def authenticated(fn):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    if args[0]['valid']== True: #if args['valid']== True:
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  return wrapper

@authenticated
def message_friends(user):
    print('message has been sdent')

message_friends(user1)
```

Comment: When a function or method has a parameter of `*args`, then it is a list of non-keyword arguments. So, its a list. In this case its a list of one element: `user1`. So to access that argument it is `args[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*args` are always passed as tuple, so you need to use an index to access the contents:

```
def authenticated(fn):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    print('A', args)
    print('K', kwargs)
    if args[0]['valid']== True:
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  return wrapper
```

Out:

```
A ({'name': 'Sorna', 'valid': True}, )
K {}
```

Alternatively, you could pass `user1` as kwargs to get rid of the indexes:

```
def authenticated(fn):
  def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    print('A', args)
    print('K', kwargs)
    if kwargs['valid']== True:
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  return wrapper

@authenticated
def message_friends(**user):
    print('message has been sent to %s' % user['name'])

message_friends(**user1)
```

Out:

```
A ()
K {'name': 'Sorna', 'valid': True}
message has been sent to Sorna
```

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, `authenticated` appears capable of wrapping *any* function, so `wrapper` has to be defined to accept any possible combination of arguments: multiple positional arguments, arbitrary keyword arguments, etc.

However, only the *first* positional argument `args[0]` is of interest in deciding whether the original function (bound to `fn`) should be called.

Implicit in the design is that `authenticated` can only safely be applied to a function whose first positional argument is a mappable value with `'valid'` as a key.

Answer (score 0):

`*args` captures any non-keywords arguments passed to it. By calling `message_friends(user1)` you pass `user1` as the only (non-keyword) argument, meaning you have to access it through `*args`.